# Is rollback automatic on SqlTransaction with using?

Tags: c#

Let's assume the following code :

```
try 
{
    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(...))
    using(SqlTransaction trans = conn.BeginTransaction())
    using(SQlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        ...
        Sql Exception occurs !
        trans.Commit()
    }
} catch (SqlException) 
{
}
```

Will there be an automatic rollback because of this exception or is it mandatory to call `trans.Rollback()` ?

Comment: Copy-paste the title of your question into Google and you'll get a myriad of duplicates, both in StackOverflow and outside. Searching is a critical skill if you expect to become a good programmer

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqltransaction):

> The transaction is rolled back on any error, or if it is disposed without first being committed.

Comment: While this is true, the documentation also states that `SqlTransaction.Rollback()` will throw - and therefore calls to `SqlTransaction.Dispose()` will fail when made without an explicit call to `.Rollback()`/`Commit()`, hence why a `try/catch` and explicit `.Rollback` calls _should always_ be used.